# How to control MobaXterm z-order of new windows

Tags: windows-11, mobaxterm

Using MobaxTerm v23.1 on Windows 11. I use it to connect to a Xubuntu host, via SSH with X forwarding. When I start a new X app on the host, the MobaXterm X server places the new window at the bottom of the Z-order; I want it to be on top. Is there any way to achieve that?